# converting Object to specific data type in toString method

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, testing

So my `node.getValue()` in the below method returns an `E` or generic data type.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder linkedQueueAsString = new StringBuilder();
    linkedQueueAsString.append("< ");
    for (Link<E> node = this.front.getNextNode(); node != null; node = node.getNextNode())    
    {
        linkedQueueAsString.append(node.getValue()); // <=== Not working correctly
        linkedQueueAsString.append(" ");
    }
    linkedQueueAsString.append(">");
    return linkedQueueAsString.toString();
}
```

When I am testing it like the following my test fails:

```
public void setUp() {
    this.queue1 = new LinkedQueue<Integer>();
    this.queue2 = new LinkedQueue<Integer>();
}

public void test_enqueue3IntegersAndThenDequeueThem() {
    this.queue2.enqueue(1);
    this.queue2.enqueue(2);
    this.queue2.enqueue(3);
    assertEquals(3, this.queue2.length());
    assertEquals("< 1 2 3 >", this.queue2.toString()); // <= ERROR since none of the numbers printed out

}
```

You can see my personal implementation of Linked Queue [**here**](https://github.com/quinnliu/DataStructuresAndAlgorithms/blob/master/src/DataStructures/LinkedQueue.java).

HOW can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could summarize your question in one or two lines. What is "Not working correctly"?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, so we can try it out. I have a feeling it will work if I try it.

Comment: So what is E? This needs more context. Also please fix indention.

Comment: Add println statements into your code to help debug it. What does node.getValue() print on each loop iteration, if the loop runs at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the problem is in this line:

```
 for (Link<E> node = this.front.getNextNode(); node != null; node = node.getNextNode()) {
```

Due you call "getNextNode()" twice, you miss one element and you assertEquals will not match.